# How to use filters in Magento SOAP API v1 with Rails 4 and Savon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, magento, soap, ruby-on-rails-4, savon

I'm building an app in Rails 4 using the Magento SOAP API v1 and Savon gem. Right now I am trying to get all orders with a status of pending. To hook into the API I am using [this](https://github.com/zben/magento-rails/blob/master/app/models/magento_api.rb) code:

```
class MagentoAPI
  def self.call method, options={}
    response = @@soap_client.request :call do
      if options.empty?
        soap.body = { :session => @@soap_session, :method => method }
      elsif options[:string]
        soap.body = { :session => @@soap_session, :method => method, :arguments => [options[:string]] }
      else
        puts options
        soap.body = { :session => @@soap_session, :method => method, :arguments => options }
      end
    end
    if response.success?
      # listing found products
      final = []
      call_return = response[:call_response][:call_return]
      return [] if call_return[:item].nil?
      raw = call_return[:item]
      if raw.is_a? Hash # this is a list of one item
        final << raw[:item].inject({}){|x,y| x.merge(y[:key]=>y[:value])}
      else
        if raw[0][:item].nil? # this is a product info
          return raw.inject({}){|x,y| x.merge(y[:key]=>y[:value])}
        else # this is a list of many items
          raw.each{|result| final << result[:item].inject({}){|x,y| x.merge(y[:key]=>y[:value])}}
        end
      end
      final
    end
  end
end
```

And then this:

```
class Order
  def self.get_all_active
    activeOrders = MagentoAPI.call 'order.list', :filter => {:status => 'pending'}
  end
end
```

This just returns `Savon::HTTP::Error` so I'm thinking I'm not formatting the request properly. Does anybody have any experience or insight on this?

Comment: Is this still a problem you wanna solve? If so, can you strip you problem down to a minimal piece of code. That's way too complicated. I can help you with Savon and SOAP call but I can't afford to understand  the logic of your code first before I can get to the related problem. I think that's the reason nobody has written anything here up until now.

Comment: @SteffenRoller thanks for your reply. I ended up using PHP to get this done and it works fine. I think the problem here is with the way Magento expects deeply nested arrays, and Savon wasn't translating hashes into those arrays in a way Magento could handle. More of a problem on Magento's end I believe. Using Savon, any request to the API that didn't require any arguments worked fine, but asking for something more specific threw generic SOAPFault errors.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this isn't too late (assume it might be), but I created a gem for this with some rudimentary documentation. I'm hoping to finish it up this weekend or next week, but you can take a look at the code and see how I'm creating the filters for Magento. To install, just run:

```
gem install magento_api_wrapper
```

To summarize, if you want to use one of the Magento SOAP API simple filters, you can pass a hash with a key and value:

```
api = MagentoApiWrapper::Sales.new(magento_url: "yourmagentostore.com/index.php", magento_username: "soap_api_username", magento_api_key: "userkey123")

api.order_list(simple_filters: [{key: "status", value: "processing"}, {key: created_at, value: "12/10/2013 12:00" }])
```

And to use a complex filter, pass a hash with key, operator, and value:

```
api.order_list(complex_filters: [{key: "status", operator: "eq", value: ["processing", "completed"]}, {key: created_at, operator: "from", value: "12/10/2013" }])
```

This returns an array of hashes with all your Magento orders.

Specifically, check out the request code: https://github.com/harrisjb/magento_api_wrapper/blob/master/lib/magento_api_wrapper/requests/sales_order_list.rb

While it will be easier to just use the gem, here's how I'm formatting the request prior to passing it to the SavonClient, which finishes the formatting for Magento's SOAP API:

```
   def body
      merge_filters!(sales_order_list_hash)
    end

    def attributes
      { session_id: { "xsi:type" => "xsd:string" },
        filters: { "xsi:type" => "ns1:filters" },
      }
    end

    def sales_order_list_hash
      {
        session_id: self.session_id
      }
    end

    def merge_filters!(sales_order_list_hash)
      if !filters_array.empty?
        sales_order_list_filters = {
          filters: filters_array,
        }
        sales_order_list_hash.merge!(sales_order_list_filters)
      else
        sales_order_list_hash
      end
    end

    def filters_array
      custom_filters = {}
      custom_filters.compare_by_identity
      if !simple_filters.nil?
        add_simple_filters(custom_filters)
      end

      if !complex_filters.nil?
        add_complex_filters(custom_filters)
      end
      custom_filters
    end

    def add_simple_filters(custom_filters)
      simple_filters.each do |sfilter|
        custom_filters[:attributes!] = {
          "filter" => {
            "SOAP-ENC:arrayType" => "ns1:associativeEntity[2]",
            "xsi:type" => "ns1:associativeArray"
          }
        }
        custom_filters["filter"] = {
          item: {
            key: sfilter[:key],
            value: sfilter[:value],  #formatted_timestamp(created_at)
            :attributes! => {
              key: { "xsi:type" => "xsd:string" },
              value: { "xsi:type" => "xsd:string" }
            },
          },
          :attributes! => {
            item: { "xsi:type" => "ns1:associativeEntity" },
          },
        }
      end
      custom_filters
    end

    def add_complex_filters(custom_filters)
      complex_filters.each do |cfilter|
        custom_filters[:attributes!] = {
          "complex_filter" => {
            "SOAP-ENC:arrayType" => "ns1:complexFilter[2]",
            "xsi:type" => "ns1:complexFilterArray"
          }
        }
        custom_filters["complex_filter"] = {
          item: {
            key: cfilter[:key],
            value: {
              key: cfilter[:operator],
              value: cfilter[:value]
            },
            :attributes! => {
              key: { "xsi:type" => "xsd:string" },
              value: { "xsi:type" => "xsd:associativeEntity" }
            },
          },
          :attributes! => {
            item: { "xsi:type" => "ns1:complexFilter" },
          },
        }
      end
      custom_filters
    end

    def formatted_timestamp(timestamp)
      begin
        Time.parse(timestamp).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
      rescue MagentoApiWrapper::BadRequest => e
        raise "Did you pass date in format YYYY-MM-DD? Error: #{e}"
      end
    end

    def status_array
      data[:status_array]
    end

    def created_at_from
      data[:created_at_from]
    end

    def created_at_to
      data[:created_at_to]
    end

    def last_modified
      data[:last_modified]
    end

    def session_id
      data[:session_id]
    end

    def simple_filters
      data[:simple_filters]
    end

    def complex_filters
      data[:complex_filters]
    end
```

I've also got a SavonClient that does some of the configuration for the specific API, here's most of that:

```
   def call
      client.call(@request.call_name, message: message_with_attributes, response_parser: :nokogiri)
    end

    #message_with_attributes are required for some specific formatting when updating Magento via the SOAP API
    def message_with_attributes
      @request.body.merge!(:attributes! => @request.attributes) unless @request.attributes.empty?
      puts "REQUEST: #{@request.inspect}"
      return @request.body
    end

    #configuration of the client is mostly mandatory, however some of these options (like timeout) will be made configurable in the future
    #TODO: make timeout configurable
    def client
      Savon::Client.new do |savon|
        savon.ssl_verify_mode          :none
        savon.wsdl                     base_url
        savon.namespaces               namespaces
        savon.env_namespace            'SOAP-ENV'
        savon.raise_errors             false
        #savon.namespace_identifier     #none
        savon.convert_request_keys_to  :lower_camelcase
        savon.strip_namespaces         true
        savon.pretty_print_xml         true
        savon.log                      log_env
        savon.open_timeout             10    #seconds
        savon.read_timeout             45    #seconds
      end
    end

    #TODO: make configurable
    def log_env
      true
    end

    #correctly format MagentoApiWrapper::Request call_names for SOAP v2
    def response_tag_format_lambda
      lambda { |key| key.snakecase.downcase }
    end

    def namespaces
      {
        'xmlns:SOAP-ENV' => 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
        'xmlns:ns1' => 'urn:Magento',
        'xmlns:xsd' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema',
        'xmlns:xsi' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
        'xmlns:SOAP-ENC' => 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/',
        'SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle' => 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'
      }
    end

    #Use MagentoApiWrapper::Api magento_url as endpoint
    def base_url
      "#{@magento_url}/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1"
    end
  end
```

Like I said, it's a work in progress, but I should have pretty good coverage of the Magento API complete in the next couple of weeks. Hope this helps you out! Good luck!

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the links for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Joel, edited the answer to include source code from the link to ensure clarity and that the answer will live on for the history of the site.

Comment: See? And that's how you get a +1 from me!